# What is the difference in using async.parallel() and Promise.all()? Can they be used interchangeably?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

Are there any differences in execution when I use `async.parallel()` ([the NPM async module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)) and `Promise.all()`? Both of them say that they start the callbacks/promises in parallel without waiting for the previous one to finish. So, can I use them interchangeably?

Comment: You don't need any package, unless you are working with callback, Yes `promise.all` don't await previous one to finish. And fire only when all promises are OK, else reject! whenever any promise got rejected... I know asking question is easy, But you should do some research first! you can found more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell they both will error as soon as a single promise is rejected. I would say the main differences are that:

1. `Promise.all` is native Javascript, so no package is required
2. `async.parallel` has a more flexible call signature in that you can pass an object of tasks and get back an object of results. Also, if you find yourself needing concurrency limits you can easily switch over to `async.parallelLimit`